# How to get variables out of a text file from an install in C

Tags: c, windows, variables, printf

Is there any way I can get variables from an install, such as the user's name and phone number and printf them in the program? How would I go about doing this? Windows based program.

Comment: As far as I know, Windows does not keep information about a user's phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetUserName()` function from winapi to get the username.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx